Have I constructed the Neyman-orthogonal score correctly?
I am trying to construct a Neyman-orthogonal score for the Poisson m-estimator, using section 2.2 of Chernozhukov et al. (2018). Have I done this correctly? If so, can somebody please help me show/prove it is Neyman-orthogonal analytically.
Consider a general exponential model
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[y_{ijt} | x_{ijt}, \alpha_{it}, \gamma_{jt}, \eta_{ij}] = \exp(x_{ijt} \beta + \alpha_{it} + \gamma_{jt} + \eta_{ij}),
\end{equation}
and the maximization problem
\begin{equation}
\max_{\beta \in \mathcal{B}, \theta \in \Theta} \mathbb{E} [l(y; \beta, \theta)],
\end{equation}
where I split the regressors into parameters of interest, $x_{ijt}' \beta$, and fixed effects (or nuisance parameters), $z_{ijt}' \theta$. The Poisson
(pseudo) log-likelihood function is given by
\begin{equation}
l(y; \beta, \theta) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_{ijt} (x_{ijt}' \beta + z_{ijt}' \theta) - \exp(x_{ijt}' \beta  + z_{ijt}' \theta) - \ln \Gamma (y_{ijt} + 1) \right).
\end{equation}
Neyman Orthogonal Score
Now consider the new score function, which we refer to as the Neyman orthogonal score,
\begin{equation}
\psi(y; \beta, \eta) = \partial_\beta l(y; \beta, \theta) - \mu \partial_\theta l(y; \beta, \theta),
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is the $d_\beta \times d_\theta$ orthogonalization parameter matrix whose true value $\mu_0$ solves the equation
$
J_{\beta\theta} - \mu J_{\theta\theta} = 0
$
for
$
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
J_{\beta \beta} & J_{\beta \theta}\\
J_{\theta \beta} & J_{\theta \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$
and when $J_{\theta \theta}$ is invertible, has the unique solution
$
\mu_0 = J_{\beta\theta} J_{\theta \theta}^{-1}.
$
Partial Derivatives
Given the log-likelihood function, we have the partial derivative with respect to $\beta$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_\beta l(y; \beta, \theta) = X' \left( Y - \exp(X \beta + Z \theta) \right),
\end{equation}
and the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_\theta l(y; \beta, \theta) = Z' \left( Y - \exp(X \beta + Z \theta) \right),
\end{equation}
where $\exp(X \beta + Z \theta)$ is an $n \times 1$ column vector, which will need to be diagonalized as an $n \times n$ matrix for further derivatives, for which we will call $D$.
Elements of Matrix $J$
We compute $J_{\beta \theta}$ as:
\begin{equation}
J_{\beta \theta} = \mathbb{E}\left[ -\partial_\beta \partial_\theta l(y; \beta, \theta) \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ X' D Z \right],
\end{equation}
and compute $J_{\theta \theta}$ as:
\begin{equation}
J_{\theta \theta} = \mathbb{E}\left[ -\partial_\theta^2 l(y; \beta, \theta) \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ Z' D Z \right].
\end{equation}
Calculation of $\mu_0$
Assuming $J_{\theta \theta}$ is invertible, we calculate $\mu_0$:
$
\mu_0 = J_{\beta\theta} J_{\theta\theta}^{-1} = \mathbb{E}\left[ X' D Z \right] \left(\mathbb{E}\left[ Z' D Z \right]\right)^{-1}.
$
Neyman Orthogonal Score
Finally, we construct the Neyman orthogonal score function:
$
\psi(y; \beta, \eta) = \partial_\beta l(y; \beta, \theta) - \mu \partial_\theta l(y; \beta, \theta)
$
Substituting the expressions for $\partial_\beta l(y; \beta, \theta)$, $\partial_\theta l(y; \beta, \theta)$, and $\mu_0$:
\begin{equation}
\psi(y; \beta, \eta) = X' \left( Y - \exp(X \beta + Z \theta) \right) - \left( \mathbb{E}\left[ X' D Z \right] \left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Z' D Z \right] \right)^{-1} \right) Z' \left( Y - \exp(X \beta + Z \theta) \right).
\end{equation}
